# What's the difference between a negation and a contrapositive?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What's the difference between a negation and a contrapositive?

I keep mixing them up, but it seems that a contrapositive is a negation where the terms' order is changed and where there is an imply sign.

Comment: Could you explain how this question differs from your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/227109/39378?

Comment: @Trevor: negation is not the same as contradiction, though the conjunction ($\land$) of a statement and its negation constitutes a contradiction.

Comment: @amWhy It is true that the two words mean different things in logic.  However, both questions seem a bit vague to me, and it is not clear that the two words are used to mean different things _in the questions_.  Note that "negation" and "contradiction" are interchangeable in many English sentences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the statement: $$P \implies Q.\tag{1}$$  Then, as you know, the contrapositive of (1) is $$\lnot Q \implies \lnot P.\tag{2}$$

Now, note that statements (1) and (2) are *equivalent*. I.e., $$\;P \implies Q\equiv \lnot Q \implies \lnot P.$$

One additional observation: Note that the contrapositive of statement $(2)$ is $(1)$, so a contrapositive need not contain any negation symbol $(\lnot)$ at all!

Negating statement (1) (and hence negating (2)) would be a statement to the effect that it is NOT the case that $P \implies Q$.  I.e. the negation of statement (1) is given by 
$$\lnot (P \implies Q)\tag{3}$$
and since $(P \implies Q) \equiv (\lnot P \lor Q)$, we can write (3) as follows: 
$$\lnot(\lnot P \lor Q)\tag{4}$$
By DeMorgan's, (4) is equivalent to:  $$\lnot(\lnot P) \land \lnot Q\tag{5}$$ 
which yields
$$(P \land \lnot Q)\tag{6}$$
So (3), (4), (5) and (6) are all  equivalent expressions, each negating statement (1).

Put another way, the `contrapositve` of a statement is `equivalent` to the statement [both a statement and its contrapositive have the same truth-value], while the `negation` of the statement negates or `reverses` the truth-value of the original statement.

One last comment:
When one speaks of the *contrapositive* of a statement, one is usually speaking about the contrapositive of an *implication*, whereas one can negate any logical statement whatsoever simply by enclosing the original statement in parentheses and negating it, as in statement (3) above.

Comment: $\lnot \lnot P \implies P$ only under the assumption of excluded middle, not in general, correct?

Comment: Post edit, referring to (5) --> (6)

Comment: The $\implies$ direction is the problem. Could you be more explicit on "accepted more often than rejected"? What accounts for the "more often" is that most mathematicians work with classical or non-constructive systems. It is not accepted in general, see eg Goldblatt *Topoi*. Similarly, mathematicians prior to Gauss and Lobachevsky considered Euclidean geometry to be natural.

Comment: Hey man, either $\lnot \lnot P \implies P$ or it doesn't. There's no in-between - oh wait, maybe there is. As justice Scalia wrote, most aspects of the real world are graded.

Comment: What about the rest of the comment? How to write that in propositional logic?

Comment: Whoops, @Sami, slow down! (I appreciate the support, just worry about "removal"!)

Answer (score 4):

When you negate a true statement you get a false statement, but the contrapositive of a true statement is still a true statement, formally if $P \Rightarrow Q$ is your statement then $\sim Q \Rightarrow \sim P$ is the contrapositive, where $\sim$ denotes logical NOT and $\Rightarrow$ denotes logical implication. You could use the truth table to convince yourself that they are equivalent, i.e., $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Longleftrightarrow (\sim Q \Rightarrow \sim P)$. Consider the following statement: If today is Monday then we are tired. This is the same as: If we are not tired then today is not Monday.